# Manual clothes spinner on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, contemporary-halacha, washing-clothes

There is a Halachic prohibition on squeezing wet clothes to launder them on Shabbat, however, would a manual clothes spinner that spins clothes to dry them such  as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CB3RKY3L) be permissible? Does the prohibition on Laundering only include squeezing, or does moving it around to sift out the water count too? Would it depend on if one plans to wear it later on shabbos?

Comment: A spinner squeezes too with centrifugal force

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't think the squeezing is significant from that - I think it is that the water is heavier (and somewhat loose) than the material so it tends to move outwards and then spray off.  I would think that borer might be a problem though, and clothes that are wet when Shabbos comes in are muktzeh, although in Manchester we often have the problem of clothes that get sodden from rain during Shabbos!

Comment: @MosesSupposes "tends to move outwards" because of centrifugal force. Without a force it wouldn't move (Shu"t Newton #2). Squeezing is just applying force.

Comment: @DoubleAA Squeezing is applying force, but not all force is squeezing

Comment: What kind of force isn't squeezing